# Convert an array of two-entry tuples into an object which maps each key to an array of values

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given an array of two-entry tuples, for example:

```
const arr = [
    ['key1', 'value1'],
    ['key2', 'value2'],
    ['key3', 'value3'],
    ['key2', 'value4'],
    ['key3', 'value5'],
    ['key3', 'value6']
];
```

I'm looking for neat way to get:

```
const obj = {
    key1: ['value1'],
    key2: ['value2', 'value4'],
    key3: ['value3', 'value5', 'value6']
};
```

So far I've got:

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(x => ({[x[0]]: x[1]})));
```

Which gives me:

```
const obj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value4',
    key3: 'value6'
};
```

I feel that I can somehow use `reduce` in order to obtain the desired output.

I am using NodeJS (not a browser).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Map Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const arr = [
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2'],
  ['key3', 'value3'],
  ['key2', 'value4'],
  ['key3', 'value5'],
  ['key3', 'value6'],
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach(([x, y]) => map.set(x, map.has(x) ? [...map.get(x), y] : [y]));
const ret = Object.fromEntries(map.entries());
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do this with `reduce` method where you use an object as a accumulator value.

```js
const arr = [["key1","value1"],["key2","value2"],["key3","value3"],["key2","value4"],["key3","value5"],["key3","value6"]]

const result = arr.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  if (!r[k]) r[k] = [v]
  else r[k].push(v)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce is a perfect use case here

```js
const arr = [
    ['key1', 'value1'],
    ['key2', 'value2'],
    ['key3', 'value3'],
    ['key2', 'value4'],
    ['key3', 'value5'],
    ['key3', 'value6']
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  // Create the key:value and append new value
  acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
  acc[key] = [...acc[key], value];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: So `const res = arr.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({[...(acc[key] || []), value]}), {});`?

Comment: I would avoid nonreadable code. It is might be cool to reduce 6 lines of code to 1, but it is not maintainable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm using this in my React/TS project to create select options!

```
export const mapToSelectOptionsFormTupleOfTwo = (
    tupleArray: ["string", "string"][]
) => {
    const selectOptions = new Array();
    tupleArray?.forEach(([x, y]) =>
        selectOptions.push({ value: lowercaseFirstLetter(x), label: y })
    );

    return selectOptions;
};
```